# How to make COLLADA models cast shadow on its own in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I tried this:

```
dae.castShadow = true;
dae.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(dae);

//spotLight is defined already.
spotLight.castShadow = true;

renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
```

But the model still does not have shadows? Did I do anything wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` to `true` for all the objects in the hierarchy.

```
THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( dae, function ( child ) {

    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;

} );
```

Comment: There are errors saying `Could not initialise shader` and `error(#201) Requires extension support`. ???

Comment: Those 2 errors appeared after adding the code. `:(` (Only in Firefox, in Chrome it is fine.)

Answer (score 3):

There was change in three.js (see [three.js migration r51--r52](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration#r51--r52)):

> Replaced SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy with object.traverse.

Due to that, now proper way for setting `castShadow` and `receiveShadow` for all objects in hierarchy is:

```
dae.traverse(function(child) {
    child.castShadow = true;
    child.receiveShadow = true;
});
```